# Why my simple tableview app won't work?

Tags: ios, swift

Iv'e made a code for a simple tableview app and with textfield and a button.
When I click on the button it adds to the array but do not show it on the table view.
What can I do to see it?

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldd: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var tasksTable:UITableView!
    var toDoList:[String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return toDoList.count

    }

    @IBAction func Add(sender: AnyObject) {

        toDoList.append(textfieldd.text)
        println(toDoList)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

        var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = toDoList[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've updated your data source (the array), but not the actual display (the table view). You should call the `reloadData()` function whenever you want to update your table view:

`tasksTable.reloadData()`

Comment: Thank you! i did it but it didn't work.
So i added it to the button func and now it works

Comment: @Eliko If this answer helped you, please upvote it by clicking the up-facing arrow/triangle to the left and click the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload the TableView after you've added the new element to the list.

You can do so with the reloadData method.

```
tasksTable.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not applying the UITableviewDataSource protocol to your class, just the delegate.

Add it and set the datasource for the table to the class?